# Cmake ignores all my directives on where to find boost in boost::beast repository

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 (with boost 1.58), and I have to develop a project with `boost::beast`. so I got the latest version of boost (1.67), and now I'm trying to compile [the beast repository](https://github.com/boostorg/beast) to play with the examples.

I compiled boost in the simplest way possible. I did `./bootstrap` then `./bjam`, and it compiled fine (and I used it).

**What I need:** I need cmake to recognize that I want it to find the version 1.67, and not the one in the system (`/usr/bin`).

**Why can't I remove the repository version of boost from my system?** Because it'll remove many other dependencies in my system, and I develop other things that use Ubuntu 16.04 as the baseline.

What I tried:

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file I got [from the repository](https://github.com/boostorg/beast), I added these lines (before everything and after the project name) [based on the docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindBoost.html):

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "/path/to/compiled/boost/")
set(BOOSTROOT "/path/to/compiled/boost/")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib/")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/path/to/compiled/boost/")
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
```

When I try to compile beast (so that it compiles the examples too), I get the error:

```
fatal error: boost/utility/string_view.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I have even uninstalled cmake from my system and compiled one myself, Cmake 3.11.2.

What else can I do? Please advise.

---

EDIT: The following is the output of cmake after enabling `Boost_DEBUG` as suggested in the comments:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1121 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1123 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1125 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1127 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = ON
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1199 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1201 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /path/to/compiled/boost/
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1203 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /path/to/compiled/boost/
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1205 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib/
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1207 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.67.0;1.67
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1282 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1284 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /path/to/compiled/boost/;/path/to/compiled/boost//include;/path/to/compiled/boost/;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1286 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1306 ] location of version.hpp: /path/to/compiled/boost/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1330 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.67.0
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1416 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc54
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1426 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1502 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1504 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1567 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib/;/path/to/compiled/boost//lib;/path/to/compiled/boost//stage/lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/../lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib/;/path/to/compiled/boost//lib;/path/to/compiled/boost//stage/lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/../lib;/path/to/compiled/boost/stage/lib;NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH;NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH
-- [ /home/user/Programs/cmake/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1883 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
-- Boost version: 1.67.0
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "1.0.2g") 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/temp/beast/build
```

Comment: This is annoying, since Beast doesn't seem to use `find_package` to find boost. The correct modern way is to write `find_package(Boost 1.67 REQUIRED)` and use `target_link_libraries(myTarget Boost::boost)`

Comment: @Justin Luckily, `boost::beast` is header only, so no linking is required. The current issue is that the path of boost (as you see from stringview) is not being taken from where I tell it to take it... I don't know how to change that!

Comment: Have you clean CMake cache (`CMakeCache.txt` file in build directory) before attempting to find *another* Boost? Also, it is recommended to enable `Boost_DEBUG` (`set(Boost_DEBUG ON`) whenever you want to know, what exactly Boost find script is doing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I built out-of-source, so I always delete that `build` directory and start over when I want to retry. So, yes, all cache files are deleted. I added to the question the output of Boost_DEBUG`.

Comment: According to debug output, `find_package(Boost)` finds compiled Boost. Probably, it is the project which uses results of this call incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CMakeLists.txt that comes with Beast is intended only to generate a Visual Studio project file when the beast repository is located "in-tree" (part of the boost super project, NOT what you get on a boost install). This is explained in the documentation:
https://github.com/boostorg/beast#building

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the info. But what surprises me is that the include that's failing has the generic boost include format, not something that's taking from an parent directory. Why would it fail to find boost in that case too in the correct directory?

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt in Beast uses a relative path to locate the boost includes: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/ce2c63ac7a9e4a0c8db227aff9dd884a66fc6474/CMakeLists.txt#L72